# insert an element to nth element in a xml in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

please consider this XML:

```
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1001</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Aba</Name>
        <LName>Aba</LName>
    </Person>
</Employees>
```

I want to write a procedure that get a number and then I insert an element to nth Person element. for example if 1 pass to my procedure I insert an element to first person element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @data XML =
'
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1001</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Aba</Name>
        <LName>Aba</LName>
    </Person>
</Employees>
'

DECLARE @offset INT = 2
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(100) = 'newvalue'

SET @data.modify('insert <NewAttribute>{sql:variable("@value")}</NewAttribute> as last into (/Employees/Person)[sql:variable("@offset")][1]')

SELECT @data
```

Comment: This inserts an xml element, not an xml attribute.  Does this answer the question properly or is the question not specific enough? Dalex's answer is more on point for adding an XML attribute...

Comment: @nokturnal: I believe the @op was talking about attribute as a data property, not `XMLAttribute` specifically (given their data layout).

Comment: 100% agree with that assumption... Since this is the accepted answer, I just wanted to point out the post by dalex as it adds an xml attribute (which is what I was looking for when I found this post)

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @AttributeValue NVARCHAr(100) = 'TestValue';
DECLARE @NodeNR INT = 3
DECLARE @XML XML = '<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1001</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Aba</Name>
        <LName>Aba</LName>
    </Person>
</Employees>';
SET @XML.modify('insert attribute Attribute {sql:variable("@AttributeValue")} into (/Employees/Person[position()=sql:variable("@NodeNr")])[1]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @Param INT = 1000
DECLARE @NodeID INT = 2

DECLARE @XML XML = '
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1001</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Aba</Name>
        <LName>Aba</LName>
    </Person>
</Employees>'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '

DECLARE @XML XML = @XML_Param
DECLARE @Id INT = @Value_Param

SET @XML.modify(''insert attribute Id {sql:variable("@Id")} into (/Employees/Person)[' + CAST(@NodeID AS VARCHAR) + ']'')

SELECT @XML_Output = @XML'

DECLARE @Definition NVARCHAR(500) = 
    N'@XML_Param XML, @Value_Param INT, @Node_Param INT, @XML_Output XML OUTPUT'

DECLARE @XMLResult XML

EXEC sys.sp_executesql
      @SQL
    , @Definition
    , @XML_Param = @XML
    , @Value_Param = @Param
    , @Node_Param = 1
    , @XML_Output = @XMLResult OUTPUT

SELECT @XMLResult
```

Comment: i need to do some thing like this:
SET @XML.modify('insert attribute Id {sql:variable("@Id")} into (/Employees/Person)[@myindex]')
@myindex - i get it on the procedure...